# How to add preloader to every http request(angular2)?

Tags: angular, angular2-http

In my angular2 app I want to show a preloader(locking screen) every time an `http` request starts and hide it after request ends. The subscribe method allows us to detect when a request is successful, has errors or completes. I think that it`s a bad idea to write code of preloader every time I call subscribe method on the request.

1. How can I detect that a request starts/ends(except in subscribe method)?
2. What is a good way to add preloader to every request?

Answer (score 2):

I would extend the `Http` class like below and add a service containing an observable / subject to be notified when an HTTP request is executed

```
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
        private _notifierService:NotifierService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this._notifierService.notifyBeforeRequest();
    return super.request(url, options);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this._notifierService.notifyBeforeRequest();
    return super.get(url, options);
  }

  (...)
}
```

register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, notifyService:NotifierService) => {
        return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, notifyService);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, NotifierService]
    }
]);
```

The service implement could be something like that:

```
export class NotifierService {
  notifier:Subject<any> = new Subject();

  notifyBeforeRequest() {
    notifier.next();
  }
}
```

You can be notified this way:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private notifyService:NotifierService) {
    this.notifyService.notifier.subscribe(() => {
      // do something
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 ways

1. Create a DataService and wrap `Http` which will be used to call the API, put your preloader logic in service.
2. you can use `Interceptor`, here is an [example here](https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/03/angular2-http-authentication-interceptor/) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2684)

I prefer option 1 which is more extendable, you can control all calls from one place.